# Less Map as multiple compile

Tags: css, less

I'm new to less but I want to give it a try. I want to create multiple `back-COLORS` classes with different classes. I don't know if it's possible to do this but I think it is.

My less.less:

```
#library() {
    .colors(){
        red: #e04350;
        blue: #106ae5;
        green: #23d54a;
    }
    ... //some other maps
}

main{
    width: 100%;

    div{
        &[class^='back-']@{#library.widths}{
            background-color: @library.widths
        }
    }
}

// should be compiled to:

...

main div.back-red{
    background-color: #e04350;
}
main div.back-blue{
    background-color: #106ae5;
}
main div.back-green{
    background-color: #23d54a;
}

...
```

Comment: See [each](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-each) examples.